# Sending object data from blender with urllib very slow

Tags: python, scripting, network

I am sending object loc rot and scale every keyframe to http address using urllib but the frame rate drops significantly.
Thats the code I am using:

```
import bpy
import urllib
import mathutils 
from bpy import context
from urllib import request, parse
from math import sin, cos, radians
from mathutils import Matrix


def RunPerFrame(scene):
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        mat = bpy.context.object.matrix_world
        loc = mat.to_translation()
        rot = mat.to_3x3().to_quaternion()
        scale = obj.dimensions
        qtX = round(rot.x,3)
        qtY = round(rot.y,3)
        qtZ = round(rot.z,3)
        qtW = round(rot.w,3)
        loX = round(loc.x,3)
        loY = round(loc.y,3)
        loZ = round(loc.z,3)
        scX = round(scale.x,3)
        scY = round(scale.y,3)
        scZ = round(scale.z,3)

    url = ''
    values = { 'msgInstruction=' : 'MOVE_OBJ',
        'rotQuat=' : str(qtX) + ',' + str(qtY) + ',' + str(qtZ) + ',' + str(qtW),
        'objLoc=' : str(loX) + ',' + str(loY) + ',' + str(loZ),
        'objScale=' : str(scX) + ',' + str(scY) + ',' + str(scZ) }


    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    encoded_data = data.encode('ascii')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, encoded_data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(RunPerFrame)
```

Currently testing with one object and the frame rate drops below 2 fps
Is there a way to make this faster with this code?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Blender issue?

Comment: Im not really sure, Im very new with scripting, but the animation slows down in blender and not in external animation.

Comment: I don't know if urllib is threaded. That means whenever it's sending data over the network, it locks up the rest of Blender. Look into threading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/how-to-run-scripts-in-the-backround-of-the-game-engine-without-freezing-or-openi/2593#2593

Comment: @MikePan Yes the urllib is not threaded, so I assume that is the issue. Now need to figure out how to add that.

Comment: @MikePan can you give a suggestion how to put that code in a thread?

Comment: @Denis can you test this now ?

Comment: I am checking it now, it looks good and there is no delay at all in blender, but I'm getting HTTP 503 and requests.py errors probably because application side cant process data fast enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [Mike Pan](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/41/mike-pan) [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2593/5113) i have tried to split the code and put the networking part on a different thread see if this helps with the speed

```
import bpy
import urllib
import mathutils 
from bpy import context
from urllib import request, parse
from math import sin, cos, radians
from mathutils import Matrix

import time
import threading


class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        url = ''
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.values)
        encoded_data = data.encode('ascii')
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, encoded_data)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        the_page = response.read()


def RunPerFrame(scene):
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        mat = bpy.context.object.matrix_world
        loc = mat.to_translation()
        rot = mat.to_3x3().to_quaternion()
        scale = obj.dimensions
        qtX = round(rot.x,3)
        qtY = round(rot.y,3)
        qtZ = round(rot.z,3)
        qtW = round(rot.w,3)
        loX = round(loc.x,3)
        loY = round(loc.y,3)
        loZ = round(loc.z,3)
        scX = round(scale.x,3)
        scY = round(scale.y,3)
        scZ = round(scale.z,3)

    values = { 'msgInstruction=' : 'MOVE_OBJ','rotQuat=' : str(qtX) + ',' + str(qtY) + ',' + str(qtZ) + ',' + str(qtW),'objLoc=' : str(loX) + ',' + str(loY) + ',' + str(loZ),'objScale=' : str(scX) + ',' + str(scY) + ',' + str(scZ) }  
    thread = Worker(values)
    thread.start()




bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(RunPerFrame)
```