# How to create a prefixed list of transform data for objects?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to create a message of transform data for all objects with a prefix, that blender will send to external application and I need it to be in a following format:

```
values = { 'msgInstruction=' : 'MOVE_OBJ', 'pref.OBJ1=' : values, 'pref.OBJ2=' : values, 'pref.OBJ3=' : values, .... }
```

Comment: can you add more details to your question as what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: I need to create a message in the format that is mentioned in the code example above, for all the objects that have a prefix in their names. Here is the original code that I'm using that works with a single object: [link]http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/sending-object-data-from-blender-with-urllib-very-slow

Comment: you can use name.startswith('prefix')

Answer (score 1):

You can use startswith('prefix') to detect objects' names start with this prefix.

I have changed the keys so there values don't get overwritten by new ones ,this is the portion of the code that needs to be changed :

```
def RunPerFrame(scene):
    prefix = 'prefix' 
    url = ''
    values = { 'msgInstruction=' : 'MOVE_OBJ'}

    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        print(obj.name)
        if obj.name.startswith(prefix):
            mat = bpy.context.object.matrix_world
            loc = mat.to_translation()
            rot = mat.to_3x3().to_quaternion()
            scale = obj.dimensions
            qtX = round(rot.x,3)
            qtY = round(rot.y,3)
            qtZ = round(rot.z,3)
            qtW = round(rot.w,3)
            loX = round(loc.x,3)
            loY = round(loc.y,3)
            loZ = round(loc.z,3)
            scX = round(scale.x,3)
            scY = round(scale.y,3)
            scZ = round(scale.z,3)

            name = obj.name.replace(prefix,'')
            this_object = {'object=': name,  name+'_rotQuat=' : str(qtX) + ',' + str(qtY) + ',' + str(qtZ) + ',' + str(qtW), name+'_objLoc=' : str(loX) + ',' + str(loY) + ',' + str(loZ), name+'_objScale=' : str(scX) + ',' + str(scY) + ',' + str(scZ) }
            values.update(this_object)
```